# Vertical Middle-Align Checkbox with Multiple Lines Label

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this long label with a right floated checkbox which needs to be vertically aligned in the middle with the label, but I cannot seem to get it working trying different ways. This is what I get:

[image]

HTML:

```
<label class="checkbox-label">I travel to multiple locations - at least 5 times a yea
     <input class="check-input" type="checkbox" value="6"/>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox-label {
padding: .7rem;
border: 1px solid #F5F5F6;
background-color: #F5F5F6;
border-radius: 4px;
font-weight: 900;
width: 100%;
text-align: start;
color: #525159;
font-size: 1rem;
```

}

```
.check-input {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is below - the checkbox always vertically middle-aligned to the label no matter how many lines it has:

[image]

Any suggestions are much appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply wrap your `checkBox` and `label` in a `div` and use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and other `flex properties` to make sure its `vertically` middle `center` on the checkbox `regardless` of the content (label) size.

Using `Flex` is rec-emended **instead** of using `float` property as flex will very `responsive` in *modern browsers* and

**Live Demo:**

```css
.checkbox-label {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: .7rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  background-color: #F5F5F6;
  text-align: start;
  color: #525159;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.check-input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkboxxxxx {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxxxxx">
  <label for="check-input" class="checkbox-label">I travel to multiple locations - at least 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locatieast 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locations - at least 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locations - at leas - at least 5 times a yeast 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locations - at least 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locatio - at least 5 times a yeast 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locations - at least 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locatio - at least 5 times a yeast 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locations - at least 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locatio - at least 5 times a yeast 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locations - at least 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locatiot 5 times a yeast 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locations - at least 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locations - at least 5 times a yons - at least 5 times a yea I travel to multiple locations - at least 5 times a yea </label>
  <input id="check-input" class="check-input" type="checkbox" value="6" />
</div>
```